# Having a file encrypted to lets know the client software got activated?

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption

I am facing a rather odd problem right now. If you fellow this : [Best place to put key or password used for encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192997/best-place-to-put-key-or-password-used-for-encryption) i was looking at a way to encrypt data. Using RSA seemed to be a good choice. However we have a problem since my requirements are thoses fellowing...

- Client must have a file encrypted in order to determine if the software is activated.

That actually mean that the client must read the encrypted file.. but the problem is that we actually need the private key to be there which isnt a good idea since some poeple could start making their license file using that key. The activation server encrypt the data file which are sent back to the client and then the client save that file.

**What are the best way to solve this problem ?**

So what i am looking for exactly is a way for thoses requirements ...

- Client must have a file encrypted in order to determine if the software is activated.
- Client sent user data to the activation server in unencrypted/encrypted form. That doesnt matter. Sure it would be better encrypted at this point.
- The activation server check that data and then determine if the client can be activated.
- If the client can be activated then the server send the encrypted form of the license file.. but the problem appear now.. there is no way to deencrypt the file on the client if the private key isnt on the client which would be pretty insecure!

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a look to digital signatures : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/xmldsiglic.aspx seems to be a good answer to your question.

Comment: I already use this with RSA. In which way it could solve my problem ?

Comment: Are you using a X509 certificate to sign/check your licenses data ?

Comment: I don't even know what an X509 certificate is so i would say no.

Comment: Ummm.. i was reading that article so if i understand.. the key of the solution are signatures. So if i am correct.. the server would send the signature to the client and keep it. Each time the license file are compared with that signature. There no need to decrypt the file afterall.. anyway why would the file get decrypted at the first place ? thoses infos was already sent to the server. But we have another problem.. how to handle stuff such expire date and such.

Comment: A X509 certificate contains your private and public keys, it is this kind of certificates that are used for the HTTPS protocol. I know that X509 certificate can also be used to prove that your programs are not corrupted. Another way is to implement a secret algorithm into your program and to obfuscate the code. Last point, there are some companies who are offering this service (for example : http://www.inishtech.com , http://www.olicense.de)

Comment: For your expire date consideration, you can implement a bunch of code that delete the signature file or change it on a specify date, the software will complain that the signature is wrong, and you can redirect your users to your license update web site.